# Spring Boot @Query Annotation for ref cursor parameter

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ojdbc

I've got a spring boot app, and I'm trying to query an oracle stored procedure that passes a ref cursor parameter using the @Query notation. This is my current code:

```
package com.redacted.prototype1.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

import java.sql.*;

import mil.af.dmcodb.prototype1.entity.Person;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    
    @Query(value = "{ call SST_JBOSS_PROTYPE_PRSN(:mycur) }", nativeQuery = true)
    void myMethod(@Param("mycur") RefCursor mycur);
}
```

The problem I'm getting "RefCursor cannot be resolved to a type". I haven't been able to find it anywhere. I got the idea to use it from a code example someone sent me via text, but they didn't send imports, now they can't find the example and neither can I. I'm honestly not even sure it's right.

Someone suggested I import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes, but I get "The import oracle cannot be resolved". I'm guessing it's not in the maven repo. Again, I'm not even sure this is what I should be doing.

I found the jar that I believe has the oracle.jdbc.OracleType in it, but I'm not sure what to do with the jar now. I found suggestions to run:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/your/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle 
    -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=19.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

but mvn is not a valid command on my system. I'm not sure I can even install it, my workstation is fairly locked down.

I'm stuck on a possible fix, for a possible fix, for a coding sample that I'm not even sure is right. Can someone point me in the right direction to just get a working REF_CURSOR with the @Query annotation?